# Black bar in right of my layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-linearlayout

I use the layout code to design the main part of the page that you see in image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
 <ScrollView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffededed">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/MortgageSelectCurrencyString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#0094ff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/MortgageCurrencyDiscriptionString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/MortgageUSD_String"
                android:id="@+id/USDCheck"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MortgageLocalString"
                android:id="@+id/LocalCheck"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/MortgagePropertyPriceString"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#0094ff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/MrtgPropertyPriceEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg"
                android:text="3463"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/MortgageDownPaymentString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#0094ff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/MortgageDownPaymentDiscriptionString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:text="50%"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/MortgageFI_String"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#0094ff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/MortgageFI_DescriptionString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/MortgageYearsString"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#0094ff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/MrtgLoanYearsEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg"
                android:text="3463"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/MortgageMonthlyPaymentString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#0094ff" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/MrtgMonthlyPaymentEditText"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg"
            android:text="3463"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/MortgageFamilyIncomeString"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/FamilyInComeTxtView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#0094ff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/MortgageFamilyIncomeDescriptionString"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/FamilyInComeTxtView" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/MrtgFamilyIncomeEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg"
                android:text="3463"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/MortgageAffordString"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/FamilyInComeTxtView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#0094ff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/MortgageAffordDescriptionString"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/FamilyInComeTxtView" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/MrtgAffordEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg"
                android:text="3463"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And include it on another layout as below(The part that i include mortgagelayout is for including above code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/AllPropertShow"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/TopActionBarMenu"
        layout="@layout/ActionBarMenu" />
</LinearLayout>
<include
    android:id="@+id/PropertyShowBar"
    layout="@layout/PropertyShowBar" />
<ScrollView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <include
            android:id="@+id/ImageInfoLayout"
            layout="@layout/PropertyShowImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/InfoLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/AgentInfoLayout"
            layout="@layout/PropertyShoeAgentInfo" />
     
         <include
            android:id="@+id/MortgageLayout"
            layout="@layout/Mortgage" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="@drawable/AgentInfo_bg"
    android:id="@+id/PrptyLocationOnMapLayout">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/PrptyLocationOnMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:apiKey="0OXLEzToRdbykr-QjEcfB9RECFS2k_Y5be7en-Q"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<include
    android:id="@+id/Buttomactionbar"
    layout="@layout/Buttom_ActionBar" />
```

the result is this image:

[image: Mortgage]

I dont know why the black bar is shown in this part.
I also have this in above of my map on this activity(You can see it below of the tab bar):

[image: Map]

How i can hide them?

Thanks

Comment: I think because you have your `scrollview` width to `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent`

Comment: In terms of that "top" black bar (on the map), I think you should use `wrap_content` instead of `45dp`, and also verify that `PropertyShowBar` isn't pushing anything down.

Comment: PropertyShowBar in other tabs work rigth and have not any thing in below of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You might want to do `match_parent` for width

Comment: Perfect :). you are right i must set it to match_parent. when i do it both problems had resolved

Comment: but it amazing i set the width i layout to match_parent why the problem of the map that is related to height has resolved?